# Quarkus logging to graylog with Kafka Transport

Tags: logging, quarkus, graylog

does anybody know how to configure quarkus to use graylog as centralized logging and use kafka as transport mechanism. I know that under the hood quarkus uses logstash-gelf library which supports kafka transport but there is no documentation about how to configure it with quarkus